# Eigenvalues of symmetric matrix 4x4

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to calculate the eigenvalue of this symmetric matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
u & u & u & v \\
u & u & v & u \\
u & v & u & u \\
v & u & u & u \\
\end{array}\right] $

What is the best way to calculate the eigenvalue. I know that I can A - $\lambda$ and calculate det or I can reduce it and read the eigenvalues from the diagonal but is there a better way?

Comment: If you take the vector $(1,1,1,1)$ you can see that it's mapped to $(3u+v,3u+v,3u+v,3u+v)$ since the sum of the elements in a row is constant

Comment: Yes thats true but how can me help that?

Comment: Then $(1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $3u+v$

Comment: Ok I see but it is only one eigenvalue I still have to calculate 3 others .... or is it possible to take the 3x3 matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
u & v & u \\
v & u & u \\
u & u & u \\
\end{array}\right] $ and do the same?

Comment: oh no it is not because the last line is u u u

Comment: You know that eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal among each other, so every other eigenvector is such that the entries sum up to zero (since it's orthogonal to $(1,1,1,1)$)

Comment: ah yeah because the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal thx

Comment: You can also see with $(1,-1,1,-1)$ that you get $u-v$ as eigenvalue

Comment: yeah but how do you find the eigenvectors do u only gues the right one? Because it is not easy to see them without the eigenvalues already calculated

Comment: I think the easiest way is to calculate $det(A-\lambda I)=0$

Comment: What do you call *best* ?

Comment: @user289143 Not entirely true. There is an orthogonal eigenbasis, to be sure, but there’s no guarantee that independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue will be orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can sometimes be faster and easier to look for eigenvectors first. When the rows are permutations of each other, the row sums are all equal, which means that the vector with all $1$s is an eigenvector with eigenvalue equal to this row sum. In this case, that’s $3u+v$.

Since the matrix is symmetric, it has an orthogonal eigenbasis, so looking at vectors orthogonal to $(1,1,1,1)^T$ could be fruitful. A simple thing to try is differences of pair of columns, which leads to $(1,0,0,-1)^T$ and $(0,1,-1,0)^T$, both with eigenvalue $u-v$.

The last eigenvalue comes “for free:” the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace, so the last eigenvalue is $v-u$. If we assume that $v\ne u$, this eigenvalue is distinct from the others, so we look for a vector that’s orthogonal to the three already found. One such is $(1,-1,-1,1)^T$.

Comment: I thin yours approach is the easiest thx

Answer (score 2):

your matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} u & u& u &u \\u & u& u &u \\u & u& u &u \\u & u& u &u \end{bmatrix}$+  $\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0& 0 &v-u \\0 & 0& v-u&0 \\0& v-u& 0&0\\v-u & 0& 0 &0\end{bmatrix}$. These matrices commute with eigenvalues being $0,0,0, 4u$ and $v-u, v-u, u-v, u-v$. And also noting that one of the eigenvalues is surely $3u+v$ since the row sum is constant i.e  $3u+v$. Hence the other three eigenvalues are the sum of the eigenvalues of the two matrices i.e $v-u, u-v, u-v$.

Answer (score 2):

**Lowbrow Approach:** Here is a possible way to do this. Notice that for a matrix $A$, $\operatorname{tr} A=\sum_i \lambda_i$ where the $\lambda_i$ are the complex eigenvalues, and that $\det A=\prod_i \lambda_i$. By inspection, as mentioned in the comments, we detect that $u+u+u+v$ is an eigenvalue corresponding to eigenvector $[1,1,1,1]^T$. On the other hand, corresponding to $[1,-1,1,-1]^T$ is the eigenvector $u-v$. Because our matrix is "only" $4\times 4$ we can denote by $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$ our eigenvalues. Then we know 
$$ \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=\operatorname{tr}(A)=4u$$
and that
$$ \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4=\det(A).$$
Now, to compute $\det(A)$ you will want to row reduce $A$ into a reasonable form. Then because you have $2$ eigenvalues already, you have a system of two equations in two unknowns and you  can  solve for  the  other two.

**Caution:** The algebra here does not appear to be super fun. That said, this *will* definitely work. A general guideline for these problems is that if you  have an $n\times n$ matrix ($n=3$ usually) and can guess $n-2$ eigenvalues, this method will return the remaining $2$.

**Systematic Approach:** The good news is that this can  also solve this using some theory. This is an example of a circulant matrix and so its eigenvalues have a specific form. It is related to the  discrete Fourier transform, and you can read about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Anyway, taking the results from there, we see (denoting $\omega_1=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{4})=\exp(\frac{\pi i}{2})$) that eigenvectors corresponding to the distinct eigenvalues are 
$$ v_0=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix},\:\:
v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\omega_1\\
\omega_1^2\\
\omega_1^3
\end{bmatrix},\:\:
v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix},\:\:
v_3=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\omega_1^3\\
\omega_1^2\\
\omega_1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, applying these to the first row, we see that the eigenvalues of $A$ are 
$$ \lambda_0=u+u+u+v=3u+v$$
$$ \lambda_1=u+\omega_1u+\omega_1^2u+\omega_1^3v$$
$$ \lambda_2=u-u+u-v=u-v=u-v$$
$$ \lambda_3=u+\omega_1^3u+\omega_1^2u+\omega_1v.$$
Anytime you have a circulant matrix (the rows are cyclic permutations of eachother) this trick will work.